# Kotlin function call deference between () and {} when lambda as last parameter

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

```
import io.vertx.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler

class RestfulServer(
    vertx: Vertx,
    private val ipAddress: String,
    private val port: Int
) {
    private val httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer()
    private val router: Router = Router.router(vertx)

    init {
        corsHandling()
        createRouter()
    }

    private fun corsHandling(): Route =
        router.route().handler {
            CorsHandler
                .create("*")
                .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
        }

    private fun createRouter() =
        router.get("/").blockingHandler { ctx ->
            val response = ctx.response()
            response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            response.end("""{}""")
        }

    fun listen() {
        httpServer.requestHandler(router).listen(port, ipAddress)
    }

    fun close() {
        httpServer.close()
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, the rest API call hangs in the browser, But if I comment out the function `corsHandling()`, everything works fine.

I found that it's not a problem with `CorsHandler` but with how I call that function in kotlin.

**Working function:**

```
private fun corsHandling(): Route =
        router.route().handler( // here I use ()
            CorsHandler
                .create("*")
                .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
        )
```

**This one hangs:**

```
private fun corsHandling(): Route =
        router.route().handler{ // here I use {}
            CorsHandler
                .create("*")
                .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
        }
```

As you can see the only difference is {} instead of () in `router.route().handler` call. In kotlin, you can omit the function call if the lambda is your last argument.

Might be this question more to Kotlin instead of Vert.x

It's the function definition of handler https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Route.html#handler-io.vertx.core.Handler-

---

The actual problem is I'm calling handler function like handler({{lambda}})

@ivo has the answer already but just clarify with a simple example,

```
fun takesSingleLambda(func: ()-> Unit) {
    func()
}

fun main() {
    println("1")
    takesSingleLambda(
        returnsLambda()
    )
    println("2")
    takesSingleLambda{
        returnsLambda()
    }
    println("3, which does exactly the same as 2")
    takesSingleLambda({
        returnsLambda()
    })
}

fun returnsLambda() = { //this is similar to CorsHandler.create("*").allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
    println("executing")
}
```

Comment: Check what the actual type of `corsHandling` is for each of those options.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What type is `private fun corsHandling() =`. It is basically what Ivo said but this way you could discover it by yourself. Explicitly stating the type is really helpful for those situations.

Comment: @TheLibrarian return type is "Route" on both case

Comment: As @Ivo said. You are creating a handler inside of a handler. Those `{}` are already themselves a handler.

Comment: @TheLibrarian you mean this https://pl.kotl.in/EAiope48wk

Comment: Yes. The inside of the `{ }` is already the `handle()` method of the handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To say it simple:

```
functionName{

}
```

is identical to

```
functionName({

})
```

, not to

```
functionName(

)
```

So when you write

```
    router.route().handler{
        CorsHandler
            .create("*")
            .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
    }
```

you are actually writing

```
    router.route().handler({
        CorsHandler
            .create("*")
            .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
    })
```

Which is, you are wrapping a lambda in another lambda. When it then tries to execute the handler it simply is creating the handler that you wanted it to handle, instead of executing it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: functionName() is without any parameter. I don't understand your differentiation.

Comment: @Vencat i added some more info. I hope it makes sense

Comment: is this what you mean? https://pl.kotl.in/EAiope48wk

Comment: @Vencat yeah that demonstrates that it doesn't work in that case. Maybe this is even clearer: https://pl.kotl.in/PT3FxPzaX

Answer (score 0):

I will use an example from Android and on click listeners on Views.

Java code for onClick listener

```
interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(View view)
}

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    override void onClick(View view) {
        //on click stuff
    }
}
```

Inside OnClick method you have a reference to the View from which the event originated. The same thing can be created in Kotlin with {}.

```
val listener: OnClickListener = {
    // Where is the view reference?
}
```

It is implicit argument of the lambda function

```
val listenerExplicit: OnClickListener = { view -> 
    // there it is
}
```

So if you would want to apply it to a Button

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    // This is already the inside on the onClick method
}
```

So when you have this:

```
private fun corsHandling(): Route =
    router.route().handler {
        CorsHandler
            .create("*")
            .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
    }
```

You create a handler {} and all that handler does is create CorsHandler and just throws it away.

This should work as well but just shows what is NOT happening and what you want to happen.

```
private fun corsHandling(): Route =
    router.route().handler { event ->
        val fooHandler = CorsHandler
            .create("*")
            .allowedMethods(mutableSetOf(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.OPTIONS))
        fooHandler.handle(event)
    }
```